# How to catch unhandled exceptions in native side with dotnet core libcoreclr.so

Tags: c#, .net, native, .net-core

I am making somthing similar to "corerun" with libcoreclr.so
and use coreclr_initialize, coreclr_execute_assembly and coreclr_shutdown in my app.

In my environment, standard out and standard err is not available.

When unhandled exception is throwed, corerun looks print out exception to standard error. (I think it work through AppDomain.UnhandledException)

I want catch unhandled exceptions in native or change way to exception message ouput.

I try coreclr_create_delegate with AppDomain.UnhnadledException but Appdomain is not public API in netcoreapp1.0.

how I catch every unhandled exception?